# how to create a Microsoft Access query that provides a default transaction type for those transactions not categorized?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2000

How could I create a query that provides a default transaction type for those transactions not categorized?

So assuming I have:

- Transactions table (with transactions)
- Categories table
- transactions_categories table - allows to allocate multiple categories (with a percentage)
- Usage is such that only non-personal categories have been applied through out data.  So there is a lot of transactions with no categories applied

Aim:

- Want to create a query that creates a list of all the allocated amounts, so would include as columns:  transaction.tDate, transaction.tTitle, categories.name, allocatedAmount(calculated from percentage * transaction amount)

BUT:

- How could I include in the query, the entries that cover all transaction that haven't been allocated, to a default category "personal", where the allocated Amount would be 100% of the transaction value
- And also (if it were possible), for transactions that have been categorized but not for the complete transaction value (say only 50% was allocated to a category), how to to cover this off to.

Example

```
Transactions
1 XXXX   $100
2 YYY    $100
3 ZZZ    $100

Categories
1 aaa  
2 bbb
3 ccc
4 PersonalDefault

Transaction-Categories (i.e. allocation)
transID  catID       %
1           1        100%
2           2        50%


Query Output I'm After
transTitle  catTitle          AllocatedAmount
xxxx         aaaaa            $100
yyyyy        bbbbbb           $50
yyyyy        PersonalDefault  $50
zzzzz        PersonalDefault  $100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the desired result:

```
select a.transID, t.name as transname, a.catID, c.name as catname, t.amount * a.pc / 100 as amnt
from allocation a inner join transactions t on a.transID = t.id
inner join categories c on a.catID = c.id
union all 
select a.transID, t.name as transname, 4 as catID, 'PersonalDefault' as catname, t.amount * (100 - a.pc) / 100 as amnt
from allocation a inner join transactions t on a.transID = t.id
where a.pc < 100
union all
select t.id as transID, t.name as transname, 4 as catID, 'PersonalDefault' as catname, t.amount as amnt
from transactions t 
where t.id not in (select transID from allocation)
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9403/7) (it is SQL Server, but should work in Access as well)